# Regex to match all words inside parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

Imagine this is a part of a large text:

> stuff (word1/Word2/w0rd3) stuff, stuff (word4/word5) stuff/stuff (word6) stuff (word7/word8/word9) stuff / stuff, (w0rd10/word11) stuff stuff (word12) stuff (Word13/w0rd14/word15) stuff-stuff stuff (word16/word17).

I want the words. The result must matches:

```
word1
Word2
w0rd3
word4
word5
word6
word7
word8
word9
w0rd10
word11
word12
Word13
w0rd14
word15
word16
word17
```

Also the result should not be like:

```
(word1) or (word1/Word2/w0rd3)
```

Basically no *(* or *)* or */* allowed

What i have tried:

```
\((\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)\)[^(]*\((\w+)\/(\w+)\)[^(]*\((\w+)\)
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WomQdU/4)

This matches those words but i have to duplicate it as many word exist which is not clean. Also i tried [txt2re](https://txt2re.com/index-python.php3) but it is duplicated as well and it is not a one line regex. In case i want to use it on a online regex evaluator and no coding is in access then i need a one line and short regex. And my preferred engine is Python and C#.

---

**Update:** 
I have added some `/` in the text. Also sorry for changing the accepted answer, All answers are correct in some way, But i have to choose the fastest and most efficient regex here.

Comment: Can't you get all the text in the parenthesis first, then split by `/`, instead of doing the whole task with one single regex? If not, why not?

Comment: @Sweeper I could do that with multiple regexe like removing other words then extracting the desired words, But i am going to use the regex somewhere later on a software.

Comment: Are there going to be forward slashes in the `stuff`?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes. The text is a google search query result and it is big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common solution is to check, if there is a closing `)` ahead without any opening `(` in between.

```
\w+\b(?=[^)(]*\))
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gClmDA/1)

- `\w+` matches one or more [word characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html), followed by a `\b` [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- at the boundary: `(?=[^)(]*\))` [look](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) if closing `)` is ahead with any [non](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `(` `)` in between

So this pattern does not check for an opening `(` before, but often that's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a capturing group which will be returned by [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) and match all between the parenthesis with a forward slash as a delimiter.

Then in the result you could split on a forward slash:

```
\((\w+(?:/\w+)*)\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\(` Match opening parenthesis
- `(` Capturing group

  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  - `(?:/\w+)*` Match 0+ times  a `/` and 1+ word chars
- `)` Close capturing group
- `\)` Match closing parenthesis

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qSdDvy/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/CSqKao)

If you want to match more than word characters you might use a negated character class `[^()/]+` matching not parenthesis or a forward slash:

```
\(([^()/]+(?:/[^()/]+)*)\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qSdDvy/2)

For example:

```
import re

regex = r"\(([^()/]+(?:/[^()/]+)*)\)"
test_str = "stuff (word1/Word2/w0rd3) stuff, stuff (word4/word5) stuff stuff (word6) stuff (word7/word8/word9) stuff stuff, (w0rd10/word11) stuff stuff (word12) stuff (Word13/w0rd14/word15) stuff-stuff stuff (word16/word17)."
res = list(map(lambda x: x.split('/'), re.findall(regex, test_str)))
```

Or see the [flattened version](https://ideone.com/avJBVR).

Comment: So i have to do another regex on the result? Or split by "/" with python?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of matching the words, you can write a regex that matches the non-words, and split by the regex:

```
\)?[^)]+?\(|\).+|/
```

A non-word is either:

- an optional close parenthesis followed by a bunch of characters that are not close parentheses, followed by an opening parenthesis.
- a closing parenthesis followed by some text (this is used to match the last bit of the string)
- a slash

#### [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xURxhl/1/)

Comment: Can you make it like look-behind assertion ?

Comment: @AidenStewart Why do you need a look-behind?

Answer (score 1):

Use `findall` with look-behind assertion

```
(?<=[(/])\w+
```

[LINK TO REGEX](http://www.pyregex.com/?id=eyJyZWdleCI6Iig%2FPD1bKC9dKVxcdysiLCJmbGFncyI6MiwibWF0Y2hfdHlwZSI6ImZpbmRhbGwiLCJ0ZXN0X3N0cmluZyI6InN0dWZmICh3b3JkMS9Xb3JkMi93MHJkMykgc3R1ZmYsIHN0dWZmICh3b3JkNC93b3JkNSkgc3R1ZmYgc3R1ZmYgKHdvcmQ2KSBzdHVmZiAod29yZDcvd29yZDgvd29yZDkpIHN0dWZmIHN0dWZmLCAodzByZDEwL3dvcmQxMSkgc3R1ZmYgc3R1ZmYgKHdvcmQxMikgc3R1ZmYgKFdvcmQxMy93MHJkMTQvd29yZDE1KSBzdHVmZi1zdHVmZiBzdHVmZiAod29yZDE2L3dvcmQxNykuIn0%3D)

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=[(/])\w+', input_string)
['word1', 'Word2', 'w0rd3', 'word4', 'word5', 'word6', 'word7', 'word8', 'word9', 'w0rd10', 'word11', 'word12', 'Word13', 'w0rd14', 'word15', 'word16', 'word17']
```

**Explaination**

> `(?<=[(/])\w+`
>
> Positive Lookbehind `(?<=[(/])`
>
> - Assert that the Regex below matches
> - Match a single character present in the list `[(/]`
>
>   - `(` or `/` matches a single character
> - `\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
>
>   - `+` Quantifier - Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Comment: Note that this does not make sure that the words are actually inside parenthesis as the title describes.

Comment: For the string given, it does work. But generally, for strings with `/ ` outside the parenthesis, it will capture those words too.